# BeautifulSoup4 Removes Namespace Definitions from Schema in WSDL

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, wsdl, beautifulsoup

I am working on a custom library that consumes WSDLs. One thing I need to be able to do is pull out the namespace definitions in the schemas so I can create a map of them. What I'm running into is that BeautifulSoup (using lxml) is removing the namespace definitions from the Schema elements.

Here is one of my actual Schemas:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:cmn="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" version="2016-01-18 Rev 0">
```

And here is what bs4's rendering of it looks like:

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" version="2016-01-18 Rev 0">
```

All of my xmlns attributes are gone. Obviously, this seems intentional, but I can't figure out how I can retrieve these attributes. They are not in `.attrs` and nothing I can find in documentation or online or using `dir()` has thus far yielded anything useful.

EDIT:

I reduced my WSDL to just the following:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:cmn="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:cmn="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" version="2016-01-18 Rev 0">
</xs:schema>
</types>
</definitions>
```

And passed this to BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
wsdl = "..."  #Replace this with wsdl from above. I didn't want to duplicate data
soup = BeautifulSoup(wsdl,'xml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

And now it is gone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:cmn="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
 <types>
  <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" version="2016-01-18 Rev 0">
  </xsd:schema>
 </types>
</definitions>
```

I can see that it is apparently removing namespace declarations that are redundant (they are already defined under different names in the definitions tag) but it changes the name of these namespaces. Is there any way to prevent it from being so smart? ;) I realize in terms of functionality of the web service request, the name change does not matter, but I would like to stick as close to the actual content of the WSDL as possible.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the smallest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/Y1a5Kl), I get different results from my test program. That's why we need to see yours.

Comment: Okay. That may take some time, but I will do that. I'm unable to provide the entire WSDL, which may end up complicating things.

Comment: Perhaps in isolating the smallest possible program and data set, you'll discover the error yourself.

Comment: Meanwhile, if what you want is to retrieve the namespace declarations, [this program](http://ideone.com/XJLIvl) does that.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, but since bs4 (or lxml) is consolidating the namespaces, those attributes don't exist on the schema tag. See my edit above, and thanks for the help.

Comment: I cannot replicate, using bs4 with lxml as the parser does not remove anything, what versions of bs4 and lxml?

Comment: I am replicating on both my work environment and home environment. 
lxml is 3.4.4 according to pip, and bs4 is 4.4.1 according to its version property. These are from my home environment.

Comment: You  are using xml not lxml

Comment: Providing the string "lxml"  as the second argument uses lxml to generate HTML objects. Not XML. The only library as per bs4 documentation that is used for xml (when providing "xml" as second argument) parsing is lxml. If you don't have lxml installed, you can't parse xml with bs4.